# Change language in Avada Theme

Tags: wordpress, themes

I'm trying to change language in Avada front-end to Swedish.

I've followed this exact instruction under "Pre-Created Language Files":
https://theme-fusion.com/avada-doc/translations/translating-theme/

But of course, I used sv_SE instead of de_DE.

Nothing is translated. How can I troubleshoot this?

(I've changed language for another website with the same theme just a few days ago and it worked without any issues at all).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you still have the sv_SE.mo file in the /wp-content/themes/Avada/languages folder?
May be it disappearded after an upgrade.

Check at this comment:
https://theme-fusion.com/forums/reply/reply-to-translation-dissappeared-after-update-to-3-7-1-4/

Comment: Add your suggestions and questions in comment. Also add proper solution inkstand of adding reference, reference may get removed.

Comment: The sv_SE.mo file was still there, but I moved it to wp-content/languages/themes, then it worked. Thanks!